# How can I imitate <nobr> tag in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, line-breaks, hugo

There are many links in my markdown code which are often found at the end of a sentence.

`Long long sentence with the link at the [end](https://somepage123.com).`

And sometimes dot wraps to a new line — that looks awfull ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4wD8.png)).

In HTML I could wrap link and dot in a `<nobr>` tag to have it keep together properly. But I use Hugo framework, that doesn't support raw html in markdown files. So i couldn't just do this:

`Long long sentence with the link at the <nobr>[end](https://somepage123.com).</nobr>`

I also tried to use unicode chars like *ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE* or *WORD JOINER*. It works good to connect word+word, but useless in case tag+word.

`Long long sentence with the link at the [end](https://somepage123.com)&#8288;.`

Of course, I can move dot inside the link tag, but this option looks sloppy and violates typography rules.

`Long long sentence with the link at the [end.](https://somepage123.com)`

Мaybe there is some other option for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should use css instead html-tag .

.example-link {white-space: nowrap}